# need to grep a string and set a variable with the same in batch script

Tags: batch-file, window

I am having one file abc.txt which contents this data.

```
{
      "versionstr": {
           "version" : "1.2.3.4"
       }
 }
```

I want to set a variable $VERSION,which should contains 1.2.3.4. Can anyone suggest how to perform same in batch script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    for /f tokens^=4delims^=^" %%a in (abc.txt) do set "$version=%%a"

    echo %$version%

    endlocal
```

It just reads the input file and for each line, the double quote is used to tokenize/split the line and the fourth token/field is assigned to the variable.

```
       "version" : "1.2.3.4"
 1.....^2......^3..^4......^5  : position of delimiter and token number
```

As the only line in input file with at least 4 tokens is the line with the version, only this line is processed.

Comment: $version is not getting assigned with 1.2.3.4, its having NULL.

Comment: @user87005, By NULL do you mean it is empty? Because in your input file there is no NULL. When the sample code runs, is the value echoed to console? If it is shown, then the code is working, but as it included a `setlocal / endlocal` to protect the environment from changes, the value of the variable will be not visible from outside of the batch file. If this is the case, just remove them

Comment: I have removed the setlocal/endlocal also and have only 2 lines into script, but still I am facing the same issue.

code:

 for /f tokens^=4delims^=^" %%a in (abc.txt) do set "$version=%%a"

    echo %$version%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56582/discussion-between-user87005-and-mc-nd).